# SQL - Accepting Strings with Quotation Marks

Tags: sql, database, dart

I'm currently developing an app in which the user can save news articles to a `database` in local storage. This is how I'm executing that transaction.

```
INSERT INTO Article(title, description, url, urltoimage, publishedat) VALUES("$title", "$description", "$url", "$urlToImage", "$publishedAt")
```

Only trouble I'm having with this is that is any part of transaction contains `quotation marks` within the `string`, an error is thrown along the lines of...

> "Calling Crypto a ‘Harsh Mistress,’ ShapeShift Announces Major Layoffs", "ShapeShift exchange has become the latest in a string of cryptocurrency and blockchain companies to announce major layoffs due to the ongoing cryptocurrency bear market.    In a Medium post entitled "Overcoming ShapeShift's Crypto Winter and the"

```
DB Error: 1 "near "Overcoming": syntax error"
```

Considering the whole article, the presence of the extra `quotation marks` tricks the query into believing that `description` ends at the word *entitled*, and thus breaks at the word *Overcoming* which ideally should still be considered as part of the `description` string by the query.

What I'm looking for is a way to prevent this from happening, so that the whole article can be saved to the local `database` despite the presence of extra `quotation marks`.

This is the whole error produced by the [dart engine](https://www.dartlang.org):

```
DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "near "Overcoming": syntax error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=near "Overcoming": syntax error}) sql 'INSERT INTO Article(title, description, url, urltoimage, publishedat) VALUES("Calling Crypto a ‘Harsh Mistress,’ ShapeShift Announces Major Layoffs", "ShapeShift exchange has become the latest in a string of cryptocurrency and blockchain companies to announce major layoffs due to the ongoing cryptocurrency bear market.    In a Medium post entitled "Overcoming ShapeShift's Crypto Winter and the", "https://www.ccn.com/calling-crypto-a-harsh-mistress-shapeshift-announces-major-layoffs/", "https://www.ccn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/shapeshift-crypto-exchange-layoffs.jpg", "2019-01-08T18:24:58Z")' args []}
```

**Edit**;

This is the full code I'm using in dart to get this issue

> Creating the table

```
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, 'saved_articles.db');

Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  // When creating the db, create the table
  await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Article (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publishedat TEXT, CONSTRAINT article_constraint UNIQUE (title));');
});
```

> Inserting the article

```
await database.transaction((txn) async {
  int id1 = await txn.rawInsert(
    'INSERT INTO Article(title, description, url, urltoimage, publishedat) VALUES("$title", "$description", "$url", "$urlToImage", "$publishedAt")'
  );                                     

  debugPrint('inserted1: $id1');

});
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use some form of parameterization implementation that is probably provided by whatever SQL client is used in Dart. You should strongly avoid doing string concatenation manually to avoid SQL Injection. SQL Basics 101 :)

Comment: "database in local storage" probably means in the browser and would be pretty much the same as in plain JS.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm not familiar with JavaScript -  what does this mean for my question? And by local storage I mean its a .db file on the users phone.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite Not sure if that is the package you're using, but they have examples of parameterization in there

Comment: @Jake Are you using Dart or JS to do this? What SQL Library are you using? Can you post the few lines of code that calls the insert query please?

Comment: @DaveC Yeah that's the package, thanks for the comment on SQL injection btw I hadn't thought of that. Not sure if it's a big deal though as the data isn't sensitive and would be hard to inject anyways as can only be accessed through an iOS device.

Comment: @DaveC I'm using the Dart engine to execute this, lemme make a quick edit to show you what I'm doing.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's hard to inject, it's common practice. It will also do the character escaping you require!

Comment: Just don't ever use string concatenation for sql parameter values no matter how safe or unsafe you think it is in the current situations. Just leads to bad habits.

Comment: @DaveC I'll heed the warning and adjust my code, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DaveC I've made the edits, please let me know if you need more to work with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the escape mechanisms provided by sqflite when doing the rawQuery.

Instead of:

```
int id1 = await txn.rawInsert(
'INSERT INTO Article(title, description, url, urltoimage, publishedat) 
 VALUES("$title", "$description", "$url", "$urlToImage", "$publishedAt")'
);
```

Use this method:

```
int id1 = await txn.rawInsert(
'INSERT INTO Article(title, description, url, urltoimage, publishedat) 
 VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
 [title, description, url, urlToImage, publishedAt]
);
```

That should also escape any reserved SQL characters.

Comment: Works like a charm, when executed though this code doesn't require the `$` before `title`, `description` etc and won't work with them, so maybe make an edit to make this clear.

Comment: Sure no worries, I've never touched Dart so wasn't sure lol. C# forever.